# Splice an ArrayList in Java similar to Node Js

Tags: java, arraylist, splice

In the Node Js code , we have the "stopTimeFrame()" method as below :

```
 public stopTimeFrame(timeFrameIdentifier: number): number {
    const startTimeStamp = this.timeFrames.splice(timeFrameIdentifier, 1)[0]

    return new Date().getTime() - startTimeStamp;
  }
```

So, In Node Js code, they are using 'Splice()' method. I don't have much knowledge on Node Js . So I just googled what is the usage of splice() in Node Js.

As per documentation (w.r.t the above code ), the splice() method adds new items at position 'timeFrameIdentifier' and remove 1 item.

I need to implement the similar method in Java . But I am not finding proper alternative to slice() in Java ?

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice method executed with 3 steps:

- remove items
- add new items
- return removed items

So i think these above steps is not difficult to implement